# visually documenting web server configuration and infrastructure

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, documentation

I have just finished a large re-organization and update of our institutions web server(s). This server hosts 3 virtual hosts, 3-4 blogs, 2 wikis, some legacy static HTML pages, and many hosted documents (PDF, .jpg, .xls).

I have organized the site into a structure of something like:

/var/www/sites/vhost1, vhost2, vhost3
.../wordpress/blogX
.../mediawiki/wikiX

Data is in a seperate directory structure so I can run a cron task over it to make sure it is all writeable and such. I then symlink to these data directories for each application.

/var/www/data/vhost1, vhost2, vhost3
.../wordpress/blogX/uploads
.../mediawiki/wikiX/images

All Apache configs are in /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.d/vhost1,2,3.conf

On top of this there is also a testing server which mirrors this setup. Once changes are fully tested, they are rsynced down to the live server.

All the wordpress installs and mediawiki installs are straight form SVN and updates are done by switching branches or "svn up".

So my question is how can I best document to share with a) co-workers, b) possible future replacement, c) myself 6 months from now. Obviously I can make a wiki page, excel document, whatever and fill it with text, but I am looking for a more visual representation that I can use to explain the architecture to less-technical people. Ideally it would be awesome if this visual representation could then be expanded to get more technical details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Visio Web Site Map.  It can detect a lot about the website automagically.  This, combined with some annotation seems like it would be exactly what you're looking for.

[image: visio]

Comment: thanks, this does look close to what i need. however i develop on linux and do not have access to visio. this should give me a good jumping off point to find something comparable though.